# How to request a navigation with heading?

Tags: here-api

I would like to use the HERE navigation API so that I arrive at the destination in a certain heading (in degrees from north, for example). This may require a detour to arrive at the destination in the correct direction. Can this be done? How?

EDIT: Also for a regular routing request, I would like to know the heading at the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Fleet Telematics API documentation on how to provide the heading for a waypoint - https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/api-reference.html. The documentation also helps us understand how to retrieve heading information in the response using customattributes parameter.

**waypoint0 ... waypointN**
required

string

Comma separated waypoint latitude, longitude in WGS-84 degree. A route must consist of at least 2 waypoints (start and destination). The maximum number of waypoints is limited. However, this limit is not a fixed number but is a result of the limit for the overall processing time. Set a transit radius by ;10000 to only influence the route to go via a certain city Set a heading by ;;;140 (degree clockwise from North) to improve map matching To define a loading/delay time at a waypoint, use stopOver[,timeInSeconds]!. Example: &waypoint1=stopOver,300!50.12,8.65. The optional specifications altitude, custom label, !StreetPosition and !LinkPosition are currently supported. The coordinates may be directly followed by ;transitRadius;label;heading. Waypoints can have opening and closing times, can be unsorted or optional. Details are in Key Concepts / Waypoint sorting, optional Pickup and Opening Times